# Create and delete pubsub nodes programmatically in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, xmpp, publish-subscribe, ejabberd

I would like to create/delete pubsub nodes in ejabberd by making calls to ejabberd module mod_pubsub using rpc calls to ejabberd node.

Can anyone tell me if this is a valid approach and show me an example of code? I would like to avoid sending xml stanzas from another ejabberd module.

Comment: did you manage to do this?

Comment: nope. it was a pet project, so after some research and no answer i gave up

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same use case and Solved using the python package

```
sleekxmpp==1.3.3
```

Find the snippet for creating and deleting pubsub node in ejabberd [Here](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/blob/develop/examples/pubsub_client.py)